# IE8: what to use in place of nth-of-type(n)?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I've inherited the following CSS code to initially hide the latter elements of a series of paragraphs and a series of list items.

```
.profileSection p:nth-of-type(n+2) {
    display: none;
}

.profileSection li:nth-of-type(n+6) {
    display: none;
}
```

Obviously, this code does not work in IE8. What is an alternate way to hide these elements?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a good practise, but you could try `.profileSection li+li+li+li+li+li {}`

Comment: that is fantastic. Are you able to use jQuery?

Comment: @Pow-Ian: No, it has to be pure CSS. If necessary, I can edit the HTML, but I'd prefer to avoid that.

Comment: I agree with EricG then. Li+Li.... or add a special class to the items you need to hide.

Comment: @EricG: That was pretty much the only way to do it before CSS3. If IE8 support is required, I think it's kosher.

Comment: @Pow-lan I agree, adding a class would be cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+`, the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), would allow you to select all siblings which are **immediately** adjacent.  In your case: `.profileSection p+p`.  (If you must do this, consider wrapping it in something to prevent other browsers from seeing it, like [conditional comments](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/conditionalcomments).)

But `+` won't help if your markup contains something other than `<p>` elements right next to each other.  For example:

```
<p>Alpha</p>
<h4>Header</h4>
<p>Beta</p>
```

If you don't already have some kind of [shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) or [moderizr](http://modernizr.com/) functionality on the site (which would help with many other similar issues), it would be easiest to add a special class to the elements, and select using that class.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a discussion on it:

http://www.thebrightlines.com/2010/01/04/alternative-for-nth-of-type-and-nth-child/

The writer mentions that you can reference specific children element by using

```
tagname + tagname + etc
```

Or get generic children by using

```
* + * + etc
```

I personally would just add a special class to those items.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try downloading and including [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/), which makes css3 selectors work in IE6-8

Comment: Keep in mind Selectivizr doesn't support `nth-of-type` for jQuery. You'll have to include another library. There's a chart on their site which shows which libraries support which properties.